# Getting a useful report from SVN - non-code files messing the stats up

Tags: svn, logging, metrics

I  have a SVN repository for my project; it keeps code, docs, graphs, etc. Everything related to the project is there and versioned. However, I am trying to get some kind of intelligent stats for my code. The stat program I am using is StatSVN - they seem to be best of breed as far as I can tell. However, I am getting results for old files, Word files, etc, and these results are skewing the graphs.

Ideas for battling through this and getting a reliable set of information about my cpp files? I don't just want to rebuild the repo, but I'm fearing that might be the best idea at the moment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I built StatSVN and currently maintain it :)

You can use exclude based on filenames and folders. Take a look at our [wiki](http://wiki.statsvn.org/User%20Manual.ashx)!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your non-code items as [externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html) and ignoring the externals when you want to run reports.

Comment: Ben, I'm looking at the svn:external tag, and I'm not following how this would help in my situation unless I set up multiple repositories. Could you elucidate further?

Comment: Perhaps you could instead set a custom property instead of of using externals.  Then ignore files with that property.

Comment: @Vlion, sorry for the slow response. You would have to restructure your repository and move your non-code files into an externals directory. It may be easier to rebuild the repo unless you need specific info relating to the rev numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not be what you are looking for, but I wrote a web based app that creates a report from the commit messages to SubVersion. It's still pretty light-weight, no real stats or anything like that, but it may help.

http://krazyyak.com/svnreport

Comment: Hm. It won't take my user/pass(Yes, I'm confident I have the right one)

Comment: Hmm... I'll look into it, would you mind filing a bug report? https://swilliams.fogbugz.com/default.asp?pg=pgPublicEdit Please file what protocol you're using too, http or svn. Just to see it, you could try using something on google code, like this one: http://wittytwitter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Comment: Filed. Unfortunately, it's not really what I'm looking for. I'm more looking for code churn type statistics.